# How to implement pagination to my table?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table which I'd like to be able to search through using pages. I assume that I will have to use JQuery to do this. Can anybody help/forward me some useful tutorials that I can use. I'm using C# and MVC so I could potentially use that as well.

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    Claim Pack Attached
                </th>
                <th>
                    Review Period Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Claim No
                </th>
                <th>
                    Line
                </th>
                <th>
                    Account No
                </th>
                <th>
                    Supplier
                </th>
                <th>
                    Amount
                </th>
                @if (Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.ClientID).FirstOrDefault() == 1) {
                    <th>ASDA Status</th>
                }
                <th>
                    Date Sent
                </th>
                <th>
                    Days OS
                </th>
                @if (Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.ClientID).FirstOrDefault() == 1) {
                    <th>
                        Nominal Period
                    </th>
                }
                else {
                    <th>
                        SL Invoice No
                    </th>
                }
                <th>
                    Area
                </th>
                @if (Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.ClientID).FirstOrDefault() == 1) {
                    <th>
                        Debit Ref
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Debit Date
                    </th>
                }
                <th>
                    Deduct Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Agrred
                </th>
                <th>
                    APL Reason
                </th>
                @if (Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.ClientID).FirstOrDefault() == 1) {
                    <th>
                        Dept No
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Department Name
                    </th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var i in Model.ReportData) {
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@i.TypeID</td>
                    @if (@i.CPAttached != null) {
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                            <a title="View Claim Pack" href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Reports", new { i.ClientID, i.CPAttached })">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    }
                    else {
                        <td> </td>
                    }
                    <td>@i.ReviewPeriodName</td>
                    <td>@i.ClaimID</td>
                    <td>@i.Line</td>
                    <td>@i.AccountNo</td>
                    <td>@i.SupplierName</td>
                    <td>@String.Format("{0:C0}", i.Amount)</td>
                    @if (i.ClientID == 1) {
                        <td>@i.StatusCategoryDesc</td>
                    }

                    @if (@i.DateSent == null) {
                        <td>  </td>
                    }
                    else {
                        <td>@i.DateSent.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    }
                    <td>@i.DayOS</td>
                    @if (i.ClientID == 1) {
                        <td>@i.NominalPeriod</td>
                    }
                    else {
                        <td>@i.SLInvoiceNo</td>
                    }
                    <td>@i.Area</td>
                    @if (i.ClientID == 1) {
                        <td>@i.DebitRef</td>
                        if (@i.DebitDate == null) {
                            <td>  </td>
                        }
                        else {
                            <td>@i.DebitDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        }
                    }
                    @if (@i.DeductDate == null) {
                        <td>  </td>
                    }
                    else {
                        <td>@i.DeductDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    }

                    <td>@i.Agreed</td>
                    <td>@i.APLReason</td>
                    @if (i.ClientID == 1) {
                        <td>@i.DeptNo</td>
                        <td>@i.DeptName</td>
                    }


                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend to use the datatables jquery plugin which offers pagination as well as search (https://www.datatables.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I used [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc%20pagination%20example&rct=j):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

http://devproconnections.com/aspnet-mvc/aspnet-mvc-paging-done-perfectly

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/implementing-sorting-and-paging-in-asp.net-mvc.html

These are the first three hits I clicked on Google I would try.

Comment: Haha, hilarious. I did look myself but couldnt find much decent info

Comment: In fact I tried the first link and it wont work for my program

Answer (score 0):

Try use this plug-in for jQuery
https://www.datatables.net/ 
I use it always :)